# Python Barplot for multiple groupby

Tags: python

I want to make a barplot of a groupby made with 2 columns. I managed to make the chart with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"error": ['erreur_qt', 'ref_absentes', 'erreur_qt', 'ref_absentes'],
"100374578": [363, 290, 154, 521],
                "100374579" : [382, 169,584, 210],
                "100374583": [213, 262, 120, 220],
               "date": ['2022.05.02', '2022.05.02', '2022.05.05', '2022.05.05']
              
              
              })

data = df.groupby(['date','error']).sum()
data.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

But it does not suit me because I would like the bars with the same date to be side by side.
Here an image of what I would like :

[image: What I expect]

Can you help me?